# Filter function for chart in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts, highcharts, filter

I am trying to make a filter function for my chart and I know it require some javascript but I don't know how to start or how to do.

I am currently using this package to generate my chart, ConsoleTVs/Charts, and I heard from people that the filter function doesn't come from the package but instead I have to create on my own. But I don't know where to start, I have look around and I didn't really help me, the only thing I know is that some people said to use ajax chart to do it so that I can filter information more easier. Maybe filter information through time where I can filter chart yearly

Can someone help me out on how to start or give me some resources for me to follow and do it? Thanks in advance.

this is how I generate my chart:

dashboardController:

```
       $users = DB::table('personal_infos')
          ->join('evals','evals.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id') 
          ->select('evals.EvalStatus','evals.created_at' ) 
          ->where('evals.EvalStatus', '=', 'Yes')  
          ->get();
         $chart1 = Charts::database($users, 'bar', 'highcharts')
                  ->width('100%')
                  ->title("Evaluation Status Result Montly")
                  ->elementLabel("Total Users")
                  ->dimensions(1000, 500)
                  ->responsive(true)
                  ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);
 return view('dashboard', ['chart1' => $chart1]);
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
{!! Charts::assets() !!}
{!! $chart->render() !!}
```

Comment: Have you tried using **Highstock** (https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo)? It has built in mechanisms called **range selector** and **navigator** that are used for selecting the time period of the viewed data.

Comment: @Kamil Kulig sorry for late reply, I will try that out

Comment: @kamilKulig I am having some trouble getting data from database, if possible could you show me an example on how to do it? Including filter function which filter by year. I manage to use until the range selector in the bar chart but I am still  quite unsure on how to do it properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with databases. I answer Highcharts related questions only.

Comment: Oh I see it okay, thank you :)

Comment: @blastme I know this post is old, do you have answer to your question now? please post your answer I need it very much Thanks a lot